# do not insert space after abbreviation if there's a space already there

Tags: abbrev

I would like expand-abbrev to operate differently depending on what is just after the abbreviation to be expanded.  In particular, if there is a space after the cursor, then expand-abbrev should not insert an additional space.

For example (assuming `|` is the cursor, `_` is a space, `a` expands into `alpha`, and a space is typed):

```
insertion at the end of line:          a|      --> alpha_
insertion in the middle of a sentence: a| beta --> alpha_beta (not alpha__beta)
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be simpler just to call `expand-abbrev`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use a `pre-abbrev-expand-hook` to delete the extra space before the abbrev is expanded like this:

```lisp
(defun delete-preceding-space-before-expand ()
  (when (and (= (char-after) ?\s)
             ;; only do if expanded with space
             (= last-command-event ?\s)
             (abbrev--before-point))
    (message "%S" last-command-event)
    (delete-char 1)))

(add-hook 'pre-abbrev-expand-hook 'delete-preceding-space-before-expand)
```

**Expanding on the given code:**

The code above is written to only work when abbrevs are expanded with <kbd>space</kbd> you could also modify this to work with any non-word character so that something like `a|-bar` expanded with <kbd>-</kbd> would expand to `alpha-bar` instead of `alpha--bar` which would be useful in lisps and elsewhere. You could do this by comparing `(char-after)` and `last-command-event` for equality instead of checking if they are space.

If you want to delete all existing spaces (not just one) and ensure there is only a single space between the expansion and the next word, you could replace `(delete-char 1)` in the function with `(just-one-space 0)`

This way `a|          foobar` would expand to `alpha foobar`

Comment: Nice.  The only change I would do is to put `abbrev--before-point` at the end of the `and`, so that this (CPU consuming) function is called less frequently.

Comment: Good idea, I edited the code.

Comment: On Emacs 24.5.1, I get an error `wrong type argument: number-or-marker-p, nil`  anytime I hit `-` or `space`.  It appears that the hook is firing even if there's no abbrev match.  This is with abbrev-mode on.